# ContentResolver doesn't find all music

Tags: android-contentresolver

i have such trouble. ContentResolver doesn't see several mp3s on my Meizu MX3. I use it as follows:

```
    ContentResolver mResolver;
    ...
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    Cursor cur = mResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            selection,
            null,
            null);

    if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to move cursor to first row (no query results).");
        return;
    }
```

After that cursor doesn't contains all the music on my phone. For example, it dosn't see my records from the dictophone, although they have mp3 format. There is no file .nomedia in records's directory /sdcard/Recorder. And if I place some mp3 in this dir and scan for media changes ContentResolver will find this mp3, but only this, so records leave invisible for it.

Could anybody explain me why ContentResolver's behaviour is so strange?

Comment: The problem may be in code, which creates invisible records. Need to see it also

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot get access to sources of recorder, coz it is preinstalled app. But may be u're right - standard player also doesn't see records

Answer (score 1):

boruno!
I had simular problem and I think I finally find the solution.
I used the cursor in my app and tried to set datasources to MediaMetaRetriever like this:

```
mmr.setDataSource(path);
```

So, when the cursor can't set data source, it trows an exeption:

```
E/cursor: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
```

After that, the cursor stops itself.
I've just used try-catch blocks and get all music files.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Azret, hmm, and how do u determine path? ) I think, that content resolver should give me pathes to my songs..or im wrong?

Comment: @boruno, it is. first, you take the data column id - `int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);`
then, you take data path  - `string dataPath = cursor.getString(dataColumn));`

Comment: alright, but cursor doesn't contain any information about my audio records, so its column doesn't contain it too.

Comment: did you add a READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your manifest?

Comment: sure. as i wrote above cursor adapter contains all my mp3's except audio records. if my app dont have  READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission cursor will be empty.

Comment: it maybe your recorder app store the records in the own data/data storage. In this case, you can't get those records. Did you try to get those records from the other app, not recorder?

Comment: sure, i can see it using FileExplorer